# iOS Universal app Architecture

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-app

I'm going to create a Universal iOS application using Swift. The functionality for the iPhone and iPad versions is 70% the same but some parts are different. The app will support all orientations.

What is the best approach for a universal architecture? 
Should I use separate storyboards and separate classes for iPhone/iPad with separate targets or use the same files?

Comment: Is the 30% change just resizing views or is there additional content being added to the iPad version? If there's not much content being changed just use the same Storyboards and Auto Layout.

Comment: Some additional content will be added for 30%.

Comment: I'd recommend using auto layout and size classes to determine what views are shown at particular sizes and orientations

Answer (score 0):

Separate storyboards would be the better option if you are planning to have very different layouts between the iPhone and iPad storyboards.

Personally, I would try to use the same storyboard for both and utilize both [size classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321339/use-size-classes-in-xcode-6-beta) and auto-layout (theres a good tutorial on auto-layout [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)) to adjust the views as @RDSpinz suggested in his comment.

Comment: What about code, how do you manage classes for iPhone/iPad versions?

Comment: I've never really needed to do that.... For me it's always been the same code running both versions...